# Will free() work on a second pointer to an array in C?

Tags: c, malloc

Let's say I have some code set up like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char* primary = malloc(10);    // main pointer to heap memory
    char* secondary = primary;     // an alias for the main pointer
    free(secondary);
}
```

Will `free(secondary)` also release memory that was assigned to `primary`?

Comment: The argument passed to `malloc()` is a pointer *value*, not a pointer *object*. `primary` and `secondary` have the same value, so passing either to `malloc()` has the same effect.

Comment: Your new final paragraph asks a new question. Your original question has been answered. Feel free to post a new question (but first check for duplicates; I'm sure it's been asked before).

Comment: Thanks, removed extra question.

Comment: You don't free pointers, and you don't free variables - you free *memory blocks allocated by `malloc`*.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `free()` will work on any pointer that holds an address that in turn was returned by any of `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`. Although doing that is a little bit dangerous since you risk `free()`ing the pointer twice. Only one of the two shall be passed to `free()` and after you do you cannot do it again with either of them.

It's a common practice to set the pointer to `NULL` right after passing it to `free()` to avoid having a *dangling poitner* and thus avoid freeing a pointer more than once "*accidentally*", in the scenario you describe you risk setting only one of the pointers to `NULL`.

In short, if you do that `primary` will become another *dangling pointer* which is as twice as dangerous as having just `secondary` as the dangling pointer.

Comment: Adding to this, calling `free()` on a `NULL` pointer any number of times is harmless, but calling it on a non-null pointer that has already been freed can lead to serious problems.

Answer (score 2):

The pointer values are the same. When you assign `primary` to `secondary`, the two pointers point to the same address of memory allocated by `malloc()`. You may `free` either one of them (but not both).

This is particularly useful in cases where you don't actually call `malloc()` or `free()` yourself.

Consider the POSIX function`strdup()`, which copies a string to newly allocated memory. Essentially calling `malloc()` (or a similar function) for you.

```
char[] strarr = "I am a string.";
char* mystr = strdup(strarr);

/* do some stuff */

free(mystr)
```

`strdup()` likely stored the result of its memory allocation function in a variable, and `mystr` was almost certainly not its name within the body of that function. That variable was returned and reassigned to `mystr`, which you then have to `free`.

Comment: To be clear, `primary` and `secondary` are two distinct pointer *objects*, but they hold the same pointer *value*, and it's that value that's passed to `free()`.

Comment: @EdHeal: I meant `free()`, not `malloc()`. (Thanks for pointing out my error within the 5-minute edit window!)

Comment: @KeithThompson True, when I said "they're the same pointers", it did sound a bit like they were the same object, but in actuality they are two different objects allocated in two different places, but that memory holds the same value.

Comment: Right. The problem is that the unqualified word "pointer" can refer either to a pointer object or to a pointer value. In a case like this, the distinction matters. If you want to be precise, treat the word "pointer" as an adjective, not as a noun.

Comment: One small quibble. It doesn't matter in the slightest whether `strdup()` uses the name `mystr` internally. Even if it does, it's a separate object than the `mystr` in your sample code.

Comment: @KeithThompson True, but I think the example still stands. I don't want the op to feel that they need to use the exact same variable name when passing around a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

> Then how come we cannot use `sizeof` or some other built-in function to find the size of a pointer array?

Do not confuse language with library.  `sizeof` is not a function, and `malloc` is not built-in.

In C, `sizeof` is an *operator*, not a function.  (Note that you don't need to declare it.)  You can say things like:

```
size_t size = sizeof(void*);
```

because you're not passing a variable to `sizeof`, but an expression.  The expression has a type, and every type has a size.

When you say

```
char greeting[] = "hello";
size_t len = sizeof greeting;
```

`len` is 6 because `greeting` has the type `char[6]`.  Because `sizeof` is an operator, we can dispense with the parentheses.  Parentheses are usually used with it, but only to avoid operator-precedence issues.

The C standard library defines `malloc` and `free`, but no (shall we call it) `size_of` function to return the size of the allocated block.  An implementation *could* provide such a function.  Compared to maintaining the heap, it's technically trivial.

Why is "`size_of`" not commonly provided?  I would say, because it's not much needed.  While functions like `memset` may operate on whole blocks of memory, they're useful for *partial* blocks, too.  The number of bytes in a block is frequently less interesting than the number of higher-level elements it contains (`struct` or even just `int`).  We may note that the C++ STL algorithms, designed a decade later, also do not operate on whole collections, but take start & stop arguments.